# PyCompileError exception

Tags: python, exception

> Write a function to check  if an input file contain syntactically
>   correct Python code, if the input file does not contain syntactcally
>   correct Pyhton code the function should print the following message:
>
> `<filename> does  not contain syntactically correct Python code`
>
> where `<filename>` is the name of the input file . We suggest
>   importing the py_compile module and using the compile function (with
>   the parameter doraise = True) and the PyCompileError exception of this
>   module.

I wrote this function, is it correct?:

```
def check(python_file):
    try:
        file = open(python_file, 'r')
        py_compile.compile(python_file, doraise=True)

    except py_compile.PyCompileError:
       print("<"+python_file+"> does not contain syntactically correct Python code")
```

Comment: Well, what happens when you run it on a `python_file` with correct/incorrect code?

Comment: It works well, but is there another way to write the function and get the message <filename> does  not contain syntactically correct Python code?

Comment: Why would you want to find another way? Your code works, it's great. *There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.*

Comment: The `py_compile` suggestion is a bad one, since `py_compile.compile` will create a bytecode file. The regular, built-in `compile` function is a better choice.